# Has ordinal index of functions in Windows API dlls ever changed?

Tags: windows, api, dll

You know that functions in a dll can be imported either by name or by ordinal index.

> From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Symbol_resolution_and_binding): For most Windows API functions only the names are preserved across different Windows releases; the ordinals are subject to change. Thus, one cannot reliably import Windows API functions by their ordinals.

**My Question:** I know these ordinals MAY CHANGE, but I want to know if they've ever ACTUALLY CHANGED. (Especially about kernel32 & user32 dlls)

**Why I'm asking this?** I heard some viruses do import win32 functions by ordinal. I want to catch them, and I want to know whether I can test for an ordinal number or not.

Thanks.

Comment: So basically, you know what you're hoping to do is *wrong*, but you want to know if you're safe *doing it anyway*? And we wonder why software is broken.

Comment: Actually I'm not *doing* it. I've read viruses do it (in "The Art of Computer Virus Research and Defense" book) and I wondered *if* a virus can get away doing it, I shall be able to catch it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is very easily answered, and the answer is **yes**. Just take two versions of kernel32.dll and look at them with a PE viewer.

For example, on the left is Windows 7's kernel32.dll, and on the right is Windows Vista's kernel32.dll. You can see that the addition of `AddIntegrityLabelToBoundaryDescriptor` has caused the functions below it to have their ordinals increased by 1 compared to Vista.

I don't understand why you would want to use this information for catching viruses. Viruses could use plenty of other ways to get the address of a function.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is irrelevant.  A virus that uses the wrong ordinal cannot replicate.  You cannot catch viruses that cannot replicate, you'll never see them.  Nor does it matter that you do, it isn't functional.